# How can i filter all users badges | DiscordJS V12

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to do a command to list every users with a certain type of flags, like **"HYPESQUAD_BALANCE"**

```js
const users = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
const flags = await users.user.fetchFlags()
const userFlags = flags.toArray()
const status = userFlags.includes('HYPESQUAD_BALANCE')
console.log(status)
```

That part of command working fine, but that's not what i want, i want to get every users

****So i have tried that****

```js
const members = client.users.cache.array()
    const array = [];
    for (const user of members) array.push(user.flags ? user.flags : await user.fetchFlags());
    console.log(array)
```

No error, but returning anything, if someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```js
const users = client.users.cache.array();
const validUsers = []:
for(let user of users){
    const flags = user.flags || await user.fetchFlags();
    const hasFlag = flags.toArray().includes("HYPESQUAD_BALANCE");
    if(hasFlag) validUsers.push(user);
}
console.log(validUsers); // all the users who have the badge
```